# Get S3Client from storage facade in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-9

I am trying to upgrade an S3 Multipart Uploader from Laravel 8 to Laravel 9 and have upgraded to Flysystem 3 as outlined in the documentation and have no dependency errors https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#flysystem-3.

I am having trouble getting access to the underlying S3Client to create a Multipart upload.

```
// Working in Laravel 8
// Laravel 9 throws exception on getAdapter()

$client = Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getClient();

// Underlying S3Client is used to create Multipart uploader as below
$bucket = config('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket');
$result = $client->createMultipartUpload([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $key,
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'ContentDisposition' => 'inline',
]);

return response()
    ->json([
        'uploadId' => $result['UploadId'],
        'key' => $result['Key'],
    ]);
```

Laravel 9, however, throws an exception `Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::getAdapter()`.

I've looked over the source for League\Flysystem and updates to Laravel but can't seem to figure out the right way to work with the updates and get access to the underlying `Aws\S3\S3Client`.

My larger project is using a forked laravel-uppy-s3-multipart-upload library which can be seen here
https://github.com/kerkness/laravel-uppy-s3-multipart-upload/tree/laravel9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was discussed in this Flysystem AWS adapter github issue:

https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/issues/284

A method is being added in Laravel, and will be released next Tuesday (February 22, 2022):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/41079

**Workaround**

The Laravel `FilesystemAdapter` base class is macroable, which means you could do this in your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
Illuminate\Filesystem\AwsS3V3Adapter::macro('getClient', fn() => $this->client);
```

Now you can call...

```
Storage::disk('s3')->getClient();
```

... and you will have an instance of the `S3Client`. (I love macros!)

You can remove this macro once next Tuesday's release is available.

Answer (score 0):

***Get / Fetch object / Image from S3 in Laravel 9?*** OR
*** Display files from S3 in Laravel ? ***

Ans:

These are only three steps to get object like ( Image, PDF, Video ) any kind of attachment from Laravel 9:

Go to project directory:

Step #1: composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3

Step #2 Go to .env and right this

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_aws_access_key

  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_aws_secret_key

  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=your_aws_regios

  AWS_BUCKET=your_bucket_name

  AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

Step #3: Goto any controller and right this in the function
$source = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($item->path, now()->addMinutes(30));

And then you can pass $source variable to wherever you want.

Thanks

Jahanzaib